# How to enable/disable particular pylint messages in VSC?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylint

I wanted to turn off the messages in VSC about using f-strings in logging messages so I found [this](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/warning/logging-not-lazy.html) which says I need to enable `logging-not-lazy` and disable `logging-fstring-interpolation`.

I didn't have a pylint extension in my VSC yet it was still linting my files so I have no idea how to actually enable and disable the above messages.  I can easily find how to enable and disable all pylinting but I'm struggling find how to enable and disable selectively.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to open a project settings file and add this line to enable or disable certain messages:

pylint.fstring: enable/disable

Comment: Could you elaborate on opening a project settings file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this `"pylint.lint.disable": ["logging-fstring-interpolation"]`